# Why is script ordering important when assigning a function to window.onload?

Tags: javascript, onload

I have a website with three files:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="First.js"></script>
<script src="Second.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**First.js**

```
window.onload = Main;
```

**Second.js**

```
function Main() { var foo = 1; }
```

When I open the page, I expect the variable 'foo' to be set to '1'.  Instead, when I open the page, it breaks indicating *'Main is not defined'* and 'Main()' is never called.

If the '.onload' event for the window isn't supposed to fire until the page is fully loaded and thus assumingly both scripts have been loaded, why doesn't the window object have a reference to the 'Main()' method in 'Second.js'?  Should 'Main()' be a globally accessible function?

NOTE:  I realize I can change the order in which I load the scripts and then my code would work, but that's not the purpose of my question.  What I really want to do is validate my assumption.

Comment: Could you please post the HTML file where you include the two files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because the code in `<script>` elements are run *sequentially* and *independently* (this assumes synchronous scripts, the default). That is, two different `<script>` sections *cannot* forward-reference each other. Now, JavaScript "hoists" `function name () {}` constructs *within the same context*, so this would have worked "out of order" in a single `<script>`.

**Preamble / warning:**

Consider *not* using `onload`. If something else tries to use it (`onload`), then something will likely break. (I recommend jQuery because it "gets this right" and "is so darn easy"... then again, so do many other frameworks. Pick one :-)

For instance, this would work in jQuery:

```
jQuery(function () { Main() })
```

**Explanation of why it works (and how to fix it without reordering scripts or using jQuery):**

Note that in this case the jQuery internal event handler is called, which calls the anonymous callback, which then calls `Main` (which is now resolves to a function-object). The "similar" code here would be:

```
window.onload = function () { Main() }
```

These work because `Main` is *not evaluated* until the onload *has* occurred, in which case all the [synchronous] `<script>` elements have been executed. (Please see my comment as to what it means to *evaluate* `Main`.)

On the other hand, `window.onload = Main` (or `jQuery(Main)`) *evaluate* `Main` right-then and use the resulting value; as others have noted, `Main` is not set ("is undefined") at this point due to the ordering of the `<script>` elements (they run sequentially).

Please refer to the note at top as to why to *not* to use `onload` directly ;-)

Happy coding.

Comment: I believe that when you set a variable equal to a function sans parenthesis, it does NOT evaluate it and simply stores a reference to it (eg. 'var x = Main;').  If you wanted to evaluate 'Main()' you would do 'var x = Main();'.  Assuming that's true, wouldn't the same apply to assigning a value to the 'onload' even of the 'window' object?  Or does assignment to events always result in evaluation of the thing assigned?  If 'window.onload = Main;' evaluates 'Main()', then what does 'window.onload = Main();' do?

Comment: @chopperdave Nope :) An identifier is *evaluated* to a value and then that value is used as whatever operand in the expression. For instance: `(functionName)()` and `functionName()` have identical semantics. First `functionName` is *evaluated*, and then the `()` (function-application) operator is applied to the resulting value (which must be a function-object to avoid an icky exception). It is the `()` which *invokes* (or calls) the function-object which *was the result of evaluating the previous expression* (or `functionName` in this case). Functions are first-class values in JavaScript.

Comment: Interesting but I think I need some examples to demonstrate.  Going to take this to chat and then perhaps we can update your answer to clarify.

Comment: @chopperdave Look for SO questions for "self-invoking" JavaScript functions; there are some pretty neat examples and good explanations. A very trivial one being: `(function () {return "hello"})()` The function-object (a value), which results from the *evaluation* of the *expression* `function () {return "hello"}`, is invoked with the final `()`.

Comment: Apparently you can't initiate a chat with someone or private message so I guess you're supposed to use comments for this kind of back and forth :)

Answer (score 2):

The second script file should be included first! That's where the function is defined. You can't reference it in the first script until it's not loaded.

Comment: I realize this is a work around that makes my code work as-is, but that's not the purpose of my question.  The purpose is to understand why my assumption is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The `Main()` function doesn't exist until Second.js has been loaded, so if you're loading First.js first there's no function-object to use in `window.onload = Main;` (`Main` is undefined). Load Second.js first if you aren't already.